# Calling an HTTP address from command line in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, http

I want to periodically call this one http address in my network. My plan is to create a batch file, and put it on windows scheduler. Is there a built in windows command to call an http address?

Comment: when you go to www.google.com or any site without specifying a page , you're still getting a webpage index.htm or index.html Gettinga a webpage via http, is correct terminology.  I don't know of anything built in.  But there is wget you can download it's part of gnuwin32(google that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your purpose and at what level do you want to do this?
There are multiple ways to get such stuff done.

If you are fine with a browser kept open,
there is Firefox ability to "[reload-every](http://reloadevery.mozdev.org/)" some time a given URL.
<sup>(if you have firefox installed, you can get it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/))</sup>

Else, you could go with the scheduler and '`wget`' as suggested.

Comment: I have this web app and this one particular http address triggers a process in the web app.

Answer (score 0):

If you install cygwin ( http://cygwin.org ) you will get a second "linux like" shell, including wget and other useful commands known from the linux world.